# Too many connections to db error, after adding an ajax auto save

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP site with MySql data base
I just added automatic save for a text area 
and one of the users received the following error:

Too many connections in ...Unable to connect to database

maybe I have to change my ajax auto save:

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function(){
  var myEditor = new nicEditor({iconsPath : 'include/nicEdit/nicEditorIcons.gif'}).panelInstance('area1');

  auto_save_func(myEditor);

});

function auto_save_func(myEditor)
{

        draft_content=myEditor.instanceById('area1').getContent();

        int_id='<?=$_GET[interview_id]?>';

        $.post("ajax_for_auto_save_interview.php", { interview_id: int_id,content:draft_content},
    function(data){ });

    setTimeout( function() { auto_sav_func(myEditor); }, 100);

}
```

in the page "ajax_for_auto_save_interview.php" I`m including the connection to the DB.

Comment: do you close connection in php file?

Comment: no. should I call mysql_close() every time in this page after saving the data?

Comment: yes, you should always close connection as soon as you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing is you should close your mysql connection every time you open it after your usage.
2. You can have a javascript variable to check whether an AJAX call is already issued and is it finished or not. Only if it is finished, you can re-issue new call

Like this:

```
var isAjaxStarted = 0;
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function(){
  var myEditor = new nicEditor({iconsPath : 'include/nicEdit/nicEditorIcons.gif'}).panelInstance('area1');

  if(isAjaxStarted == 0)
      auto_save_func(myEditor);

});

function auto_save_func(myEditor)
{
        isAjaxStarted = 1;
        draft_content=myEditor.instanceById('area1').getContent();

        int_id='<?=$_GET[interview_id]?>';

        $.post("ajax_for_auto_save_interview.php", { interview_id: int_id,content:draft_content},
    function(data){ isAjaxStarted = 0; });

    setTimeout( function() { auto_sav_func(myEditor); }, 100);

}
```

Comment: Thank You. You added the if in onDomLoaded function that calls ajax only the first time. It continues call it after the AJAx in the second function,Isn't it automatically continuing only after returning from the AJAX?

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. Yes it should be added in setTimeout function as well.

Comment: Isn't it calls setTimeout only after returning from Ajax?

Comment: Nope. Since it is an asynchronous call, it'll not wait for AJAX to get complete.

Comment: Why not to call the setTimeOut in the function(data) when returning from the Ajax? <br>can i do like that:<br>  function report_auto_save(myEditor)
 {
........

            $.post("ajax_for_auto_save_interview.php", { interview_id: int_id,content:draft_content},
   function(data){
                 setTimeout( function() { report_auto_save(myEditor); }, 3000);
                 });
    
 }

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am writing late you help in place it? thank you very much

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
      var myNicEditor = new nicEditor({buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','left','center','right','justify',/*'ol','ul',*/'forecolor',/*'fontSize','fontFamily',*//*'fontFormat',*//*'indent','outdent',*/'image','upload','link','unlink'/*,'bgcolor'*/,'hr','removeformat', 'youTube'/*,'subscript','superscript'*/],/*fullPanel : true,*/ 
      iconsPath : '<? echo "".$IndirizzoPagina."".$IndirizzoCartella."";?>default/image/EditorDiTesto/nicEditorIcons.gif'});
      myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicPanel'); //PANNELLO DI CONTROLLO
      myNicEditor.addInstance('titolo'); //TITOLO
      myNicEditor.addInstance('contenuto'); //CONTENUTO
 });
```

```
<textarea name='contenuto' id='contenuto' class='box2'>".$ContenutoNotizia."</textarea>"
```

i used this code http://nicedit.com/